# TextField is not following the conditions

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, awt, textfield

here's a quick explanation, I make my TextField into false condition inside of .setEnabled area. So basically after the user press check on Cake's check-box, he need to choose either one of the sub-item menu, after he do that, he needs to enter the quantity of the cake. But, after choosing the sub-item menu, the TextField condition should be true(means it should be editable), but it doesn't go as were told. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

class testingcheckbox
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Frame qB = new Frame("Queen Bakery");

    JCheckBox cake;

    cake = new JCheckBox("Cake");
    JCheckBox cakeOpt1 = new JCheckBox("Butter Cake");
    JCheckBox cakeOpt2 = new JCheckBox("Cheese Cake");

    TextField tfCake = new TextField();
    tfCake.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,24));
    tfCake.setEnabled(false);

    ActionListener cakeListener = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(cake.isSelected())
            {
                cakeOpt1.setEnabled(true);
                cakeOpt2.setEnabled(true);

                if(cakeOpt1.isSelected())
                {
                    tfCake.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    tfCake.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cakeOpt1.setEnabled(false);
                cakeOpt2.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    };

    cake.addActionListener(cakeListener);
    qB.add(cake);

    cakeOpt1.setEnabled(false);
    cakeOpt2.setEnabled(false);
    qB.add(cakeOpt1);
    qB.add(cakeOpt2);

    qB.add(tfCake);

    qB.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }        
    });

    qB.setSize(780,470);
    qB.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    qB.setVisible(true);
    qB.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    qB.setResizable(false);
 }
}
```

Comment: The best way to get us to fully and quickly understand your problem would be if you were to to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

Comment: The ActionListener seems ok... are you sure you are calling it when cakeOpt1 or cakeOpt2 is clicked.

Comment: Don't use AWT (Frame, TextField) components. Use Swing components (JFrame, JTextField).

Comment: already change it, still nothing. what basically i learn from my lecturer, he said that there is actually no problem if the components combined from different packages(correct me if i'm wrong).

Comment: That was not meant to solve the problem. You should NOT be using AWT components in a Swing application that is why it was just a comment. Be consistent in your code.

Comment: I got your point, thank you kindly sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cake.addActionListener(cakeListener);
```

You only add the ActionListener to one check box so no code is execute when you click on the "optonal" check boxes.

You also need to add your ActionListener to your other check boxes:

```
cakeOpt1.addActionListener(cakeListener);
cakeOpt2.addActionListener(cakeListener);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.